# rewrite a variable inside a async function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I want to rewrite the variable `output` inside the `async function(user)`. I tried after the `.forEach(async function (user)` to add `.then` and `finally()` but the `console.log(output)` stays everywhere empty.

```
async function findData() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
    if (!client) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      var code = "";
      const db = client.db(dbname);
      let collection = db.collection('user');
      let res = await collection.find(status: 'open').forEach(
        async function (user) {
          output = "User: " + user._id + " - " + await city(user.city) + output;
        });
        console.log(output); // the result is here ""
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      console.log(output); // the result is here ""
      client.close();
      return;
    }
  }
findData();
```

Is there a way to await the `async function (user)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "the variable code" you mean "the variable output"? `forEach` doesn't await callbacks, it's sync. Use e.g. `for ... of` with an `await`, you'll be happier.

Comment: also [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: So I can use the variable `res` (the result of the `await collection.find`) to generate the variable `output` and reuse it `output` then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking to do since you talk about rewriting the variable `code` but you are printing `output` and not reassigning `code`.

However, what you should know is that in javascript `.forEach` is not asynchronous. It doesn't wait for the `async function` to terminate and triggers everything at the same time.
Use a for loop instead like:

```js
let res = await collection.find(status: 'open');
for (user of res) {
    output = "User: " + user._id + " - " + await city(user.city) + output;
    console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I mean the variable "output".(edited now) 
When I `console.log(res);` it says `null` so I never tried your suggestion, I will try it out. Can reuse the variable `output` or does it stay inside the `for()`-block?

Comment: When I try it with `for of` I get the error `TypeError: res is not iterable`. :(

Comment: In your example `output` is not define in your for loop (no `let` or `const` keyword, so I assume it was defined before in your code and therefore you can use it outside the loop. However if you only define it in the loop, you can only use it in the loop. Do `let output` before

Comment: Actually, I don't know what is the type of `res` maybe res is actually no the object you want to iterate on but `res.documents` or whatever? You can also try a classic `for` loop `for (let i=0; i<res.length; i++) { const user = res[i]; ... }`